# Issues with enumeration and loops in C++

Tags: c++, class, vector, enums

I'm working on a turn-based RPG for a class project, but I can't figure out how to properly use enumerators to represent characters in my class function for generating maps by transferring the contents of a text file to a 2D vector named "map". My compiler is also detecting errors in the vector loops I use for generating entities on the map, but I believe those have to do with the enumerators.

What am I doing wrong with my implementation of enumerators, and what can I do to fix it?

**Code (Map.cpp):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

#include "Map.h"

enum Terrain {
    water = '~',
    open = '*',
    
    wall1 = '-',
    wall2 = '|',
    
    stairUp = '<',
    stairDown = '>'
};

enum Entities {
    player = '@',
    bandit = 'B',
    crew = 'c',
    captain = 'C'
};

void Map::GenMap(std::string name) {
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    
    //If name is "default", generate pre-made test map
    if (name == "default") {
        map = {{'~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~'},
               {'~','~','-','-','-','-','-','~','~'},
               {'~','|','*','*','B','*','*','|','~'},
               {'~','|','*','*','*','*','*','|','~'},
               {'~','|','*','*','*','*','*','|','~'},
               {'~','|','*','*','*','*','*','|','~'},
               {'~','|','*','*','@','*','*','|','~'},
               {'~','~','-','-','-','-','-','~','~'},
               {'~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~'}};
    }
    else {
        //Open map file of the same name as parameter
        std::ifstream mapFile;
        mapFile.open(name);
        
        //Copy contents of map to 2D vector
        if (mapFile.is_open()) {
            std::string str;
            getline(mapFile, str);
            
            
        } //Closes if statement
        mapFile.close();
        
    } //Closes else statement
    
}

void Map::SpawnEntities() {
    int randNum1 = rand() % 16;
    
    //Spawn Player
    for(int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) { //Row size
        bool placedPlayer = false;
        for(int k = 0; k < map.at(i).size(); k++) { //Column size
            int thisRandNum = rand() % 16;
            if((thisRandNum == randNum1) && (map.at[i][k] == Terrain::open)) {
                map.at[i][k] = Entities::player;
                placedPlayer = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(placedPlayer == true) {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    //Spawn enemies
    int mapSeverity = (rand() % 5) + 1; //Enemy # multiplier between 1-5
    int numEntities = ((rand() % 4) + 1) * mapSeverity; //# of enemies spawned
    
    std::vector<Entities> includeEntities;
    std::vector<int> numSpawns;
    
    switch(mapSeverity) {
        case 5:
        case 4:
            includeEntities.push_back(Entities::captain);
        case 3:
            includeEntities.push_back(Entities::crew);
        case 2:
        case 1:
            includeEntities.push_back(Entities::bandit);
    }
    
    int randNum2 = rand() % 16;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) { //Row
        for(int k = 0; i < map.at(i).size(); k++) { //Column
            int thisRandNum = rand() % 16;
            if((thisRandNum == randNum2) && (map.at[i][k] == Terrain::open)) {
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Compiler Error:**

```
g++ -Wall -c "Map.cpp" (in directory: /home/herodegon/Documents/CodingProjects/C++/ECGR2104/rpg_Project)
Map.cpp: In member function ‘void Map::GenMap(std::string)’:
Map.cpp:29:6: warning: unused variable ‘width’ [-Wunused-variable]
   29 |  int width = 0;
      |      ^~~~~
Map.cpp:30:6: warning: unused variable ‘height’ [-Wunused-variable]
   30 |  int height = 0;
      |      ^~~~~~
Map.cpp: In member function ‘void Map::SpawnEntities()’:
Map.cpp:66:19: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<std::vector<char> >::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
   66 |  for(int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) { //Row size
      |                 ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
Map.cpp:68:20: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<char>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
   68 |   for(int k = 0; k < map.at(i).size(); k++) { //Column size
      |                  ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Map.cpp:70:43: error: invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’ for array subscript
   70 |    if((thisRandNum == randNum1) && (map.at[i][k] == Terrain::open)) {
      |                                           ^
Map.cpp:71:11: error: invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’ for array subscript
   71 |     map.at[i][k] = Entities::player;
      |           ^
Map.cpp:101:19: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<std::vector<char> >::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  101 |  for(int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) { //Row
      |                 ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
Map.cpp:102:20: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<char>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
  102 |   for(int k = 0; i < map.at(i).size(); k++) { //Column
      |                  ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Map.cpp:104:43: error: invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’ for array subscript
  104 |    if((thisRandNum == randNum2) && (map.at[i][k] == Terrain::open)) {
      |                                           ^
Map.cpp:83:6: warning: unused variable ‘numEntities’ [-Wunused-variable]
   83 |  int numEntities = ((rand() % 4) + 1) * mapSeverity; //# of enemies spawned
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~
Compilation failed.
```

*Edit: This is very much W.I.P. Some of the code, like the SpawnEntities() function, are incomplete.

Comment: Slightly tangential, but you should use `enum class` instead of `enum`. https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/enum-classes/

Comment: You need to format error messages as code block so they will be displayed properly. Also switch cases typically require a `break;`

Comment: Also, can you create a small reproducible example on repl.it or something we can run to see the compiler error?

Comment: @user7860670 I should have mentioned that this is very W.I.P. The entity section is my most recent addition. I'll add it to the post.

Comment: @Gillespie They were enum class at first, but I changed them when I saw an example that didn't used them and wondered if doing so would fix my issue. I'll change it back.

Comment: @user7860670 Regarding the switches: depending on int mapIntensity, the map will include different categories of enemies while still including ones from the previous tiers. So for instance mapIntensity of 1 will only include bandits, but a mapIntensity of 4 will include captains, crew members, and bandits.

Comment: I've added the compiler error to the post.

Comment: `map.at[i][k]` should be `map.at(i).at(k)` or `map[i][k]` depending if you want range exceptions or not.

Comment: Many of those warnings should be easy to fix. 1) Remove unused variables 2) Don't compare signed and unsigned types.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah OH MY GOD, I COMPLETELY MISSED THAT! Thank you so much!

Comment: @TedLyngmo I usually ignore warnings like that, especially the one's about comparing signed and unsigned integers, as I usually don't declare any in my programs. Should I?

Comment: @Herodegon Well, even if you ignore them, all those warnings makes it harder to see the real problems. In your loops you could use `size_t` instead of `int` which makes sense since `size()` returns a  `size_t`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those errors are pretty descriptive, but I'll grab a few:

```
Map.cpp:66:19: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<std::vector<char> >::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
66 |  for(int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) { //Row size
```

It's just a warning, but map.size() returns a size_t (unsigned long). Use:

```
for (size_t i = 0...) 


Map.cpp:70:43: error: invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’ for array subscript
70 |    if((thisRandNum == randNum1) && (map.at[i][k] == Terrain::open)) {
```

You have square braces. Either do `map[]` or `map.at()`.

I think the rest is more of the same

Comment: @JerryJeremiah posted about that, too. I have no idea how I missed the `map.at[i][k]` thing, but I've done it before. Thanks for the help.

Comment: When it comes to comparing `signed` and `unsigned` variables, I've always ignored the warnings because I just usually don't declare any of my variables as either. Should I from now on? What does it mean when a variable is declared with `signed` or `unsigned`.

Comment: @Herodegon I like my code to compile cleanly. It's only a problem if the size of your container grows to more than a signed int can handle, which is rare for most of us, most of the time, but it can happen. As this particular case is trivial to handle, it's worth handling it properly and getting into the habit.

Comment: @Herodegon `int` is the same as `signed int` and `unsigned` is the same as `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

> "`map.at[i][k]` should be `map.at(i).at(k)` or `map[i][k]` depending if
> you want range exceptions or not."
>
> - [Jerry Jeremiah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2193968/jerry-jeremiah)